# Generate a pseudorandom stream with entropy parameters

Tags: algorithm, random, entropy, information-theory

How can I generate a stream of binary outcomes of length *n* with an equal number of 0's and 1's but with a biased frequency of pairwise outcomes, i.e. given alternation rate *k* `( freq(01) + freq(10) ) / ( freq(00) + freq(11) ) = k`

Answer (score 1):

Generate a random markov chain with the following transition probability:

```
        0       1
0   1/(k+1)  k/(k+1)

1   k/(k+1)  1/(k+1)
```

Essentially, if you just generated 0, generate another 0 with probability 1/(k+1)

Note: If you want to guarantee the requirements use the following approach

Let us assume you want to generate mk unequal combinations and m equal combinations.

1. Let reserve_eq = m and reserve_uneq=mk.
2. Generate a random bit 0/1 with equal probability. Let cur be that bit
3. Output cur
4. Generate new_cur = (cur,1-cur) with weighted probability (reserve_eq,reserve_uneq)
5. If new_cur= cur then decrement reserve_eq, otherwise decrement reserve_uneq
6. cur = new_cur
7. Goto Step 3

In step 4 quit if both reserve_eq and reserve_uneq are both zero. The output string is of length km+m+1.

Comment: I like the line of thinking, but in order to guarantee the requirements *n* has be to infinite

Comment: @nick see my additional answer